# Adding rows dynamically in QTP based on values in an existing column

Tags: datatable, qtp

Is it possible to add a new row dynamically during run time on the QTP datatable or excel sheet?  It has to be dynamic because adding the new row depends on how many rows of data the input data returns.  It doesn't look like there is any method that adds rows either in the datatable or excel so I am not sure how to deal with this issue.

The datatable:  6 columns and currently testing with 4 account numbers for now as rows so it looks something like this:

column 1, column 2, column 3, column 4, column 5, column 6
account 1
account 2
account 3
account 4

The application:  Web app that has account number as input, and can return multiple rows of data.  Currently, if an account number returns multiple rows of data, it over rides the previous entry.  I need it to create a new row under the previous row (so that it doesn't a.) override previous entry and b.) enter previous accounts information on the next account's line.

Here is the pseudo code for review:

```
Dim Rowcount, webrowcnt
Rowcount=datatable.getsheet"Sheet name".GetRowCount

For i=1 to Rowcount
Datatable.GetSheet"Sheet name".SetCurrentRow(i)
Browser("").Page("").Link("").Click
Browser("").Page("").WebEdit("").Set DataTable("Row1", dtLocalSheet)
Browser("").Page("").WebButton("").Click

webrowcnt=Browser("").Page("").WebTable("").RowCount

For n=3 to webrowcnt  (note: n=3 because the data I need starts on row 3)
If webrowcnt > 3 Then (note: this is where I want it to create a new row if there is more than 3 rows of data)
For i=4 to webrowcnt
some code here to create however many rows of data the account number has.
Next
End If
column1 = Browser("").Page("").WebTable("").GetCellData(n, 1)
DataTable("column1", dtLocalSheet)=column1
column2 = Browser("").Page("").WebTable("").GetCellData(n, 2)
DataTable("column2", dtLocalSheet)=column2
column3 = Browser("").Page("").WebTable("").GetCellData(n, 3)
DataTable("column3", dtLocalSheet)=column3
column4 = Browser("").Page("").WebTable("").GetCellData(n, 4)
DataTable("column4", dtLocalSheet)=column4
column5 = Browser("").Page("").WebTable("").GetCellData(n, 5)
DataTable("column5", dtLocalSheet)=column5
column6 = Browser("").Page("").WebTable("").GetCellData(n, 6)
DataTable("column6", dtLocalSheet)=column6

Browser("").Page("").Link("").click (note: link to return to home page to  restart on new account number)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the combination of **get** and **set** method of Datatable

```
rowNum=DataTable.GetCurrentRow
DataTable.setCurrentRow(rowNum+1)
```

Please check the syntax in UFT(QTP), by focusing on the Datatable and press F1.

Hope this would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can just keep on inserting the values to the next rows and in the end export the inserted values to external file

```
for n=3 to webrowcnt
......some code.......
  If webrowcnt > 3  then 
    DataTable.SetCurrentRow(n) 'now value of n is 4 and so on
    DataTable.Value("parameter","sheet")="Value" 'fill any data you want
   ......some code.......
   end IF
......some code.......
next
```